# Loop to run processes from quantity to quantity

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a list of size 30 in python, I need to loop to get 6 item from this run list, after we finish the 6 run plus 6 and so on until I finish the list.

but I am not finding a way to do that.

```
import them
    scripts [
    'exp1.py'
    'exp2.py'
    'exp3.py'
    'exp4.py'
    [...]
    'exp30.py'
    ]
def process_wheel (process):
    os.system ('python {}'. format (process))
```

run:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from scripts import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_processors = # [need to run here 6 out of 6]

    pool = Pool (processes = num_processors)
    output = pool.map (process_wheel, processes)
    print (output)
```

Because I need to only run 6 processes at a time and when finishing one run the others.

Comment: look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031373/run-process-after-process-in-a-queue-using-python/58031742#58031742

Comment: @Marc As the implementation would be in my case, I couldn't detect where I can pass my list of processes in this code.

Comment: it's called queue in the question. That is a list of strings I believe that describe which subprocesses should be started.